# Move video files to directory by width

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to move video files to directory by width of that video file.

For example I have

```
./xxx/pr0n.mkv
./pokemon.mkv
```

After running script

```
./xxx/1920/pr0n.mkv
./1920/pokemon.mkv
```

If I run script again another width directory is not created.

- Match common video extensions
- Do **not** match if file's parent directory is only digits (because that's the width)

I've come up with this so far but it doesn't work:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.mov" -o -iname "*.mpg" -o -iname "*.mpeg" -o -iname "*.wmv" -o -iname "*.mp4" \) -a -regex '.*\/[^0-9]+\/\.*$' -exec bash -c 'echo "Processing {} .."; WIDTH=$(mediainfo "--Inform=Video;%Width%" "{}") && DIR=$(dirname "{}") && mkdir -p "$DIR/$WIDTH" && mv "{}" "$DIR/$WIDTH"' \;
```

Comment: Glad were here to help you organize your pr0n 8-).

Answer (score 1):

I found your question:
use `ffmpeg -i YOUR_MOVIE_FILES -sample_fmts` You get the long data.

You must use a true `grep` to retrieve resolution. in this data you can find resolution.

`ffmpeg -i YOUR_MOVIE_FILES -sample_fmts |egrep blahblah`

or use a `awk script`.